# Which event to open a wxToolBar drop-down menu?

Tags: c++, events, drop-down-menu, toolbar, wxwidgets

I'm using a wxToolBar with an drop-down item:

```
g_toolBar1->AddTool(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,_("Control elements"),MainWin::getBitmap(gearsXPM,"gears"),wxNullBitmap,wxITEM_DROPDOWN);
custParent->Connect(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,wxEVT_COMMAND_TOOL_CLICKED,wxCommandEventHandler(DrawCanvasSwitcher::OnToolbar),NULL,g_drawCanvas);
.... // add items to controlMenu here
g_toolBar1->SetDropdownMenu(TOOLBAR_CMD_CONTROL_DROPDOWN,controlMenu);
```

The drop-down menu opens automatically when somebody left-clicks the arrow right beside the tool. But what event do I have to send to open the drop-down menu programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open any menu, also a drop down menu by calling [PopupMenu](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_window.html#a8f715d238cf74a845488b0e2645e98df):

```
bool wxWindow::PopupMenu (wxMenu*        menu,
                          const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition);
```

So in your case it should be:

```
yourWxWindow->PopupMenu(controlMenu);
```

or when you are already in a class that inherits from wxWindow:

```
PopupMenu(controlMenu);
```